# Gradle project compiler missing classes presumably from tools.jar

Tags: java, gradle, build

This one is completely beyond me. :-/
Will take any trouble shooting tips I can get.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':commons:stuf-widgets:compileJava'.
> com/sun/tools/javac/util/Log$PrefixKind
```

The above resulted from:

```
gradle clean;gradle build
```

Fix I tried:

```
compile files("${System.properties['java.home']}/../lib/tools.jar")
```

Got that from another question wherein a class that should have been in tools.jar was not loaded. Adding it changed nothing. I don't see anything special about the dependencies. Using `--stacktrace --debug --info` did not provide any additional clues other than as noted above. There is nothing special going on like JAXB or WSDL generation.

Environment:

```
    me@mybox-me ~ $ java -version
    java version "1.8.0_66"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
    me@mybox-me ~ $ which gradle
    /####/#######/gradle/bin/gradle
    me@mybox-me ~ $ which groovy
    /####/#######/groovy/bin/groovy

    gradle --version

    ------------------------------------------------------------
    Gradle 2.8
    ------------------------------------------------------------

    Build time:   2015-10-20 03:46:36 UTC
    Build number: none
    Revision:     b463d7980c40d44c4657dc80025275b84a29e31f

    Groovy:       2.4.4
    Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
    JVM:          1.8.0_66 (Oracle Corporation 25.66-b17)
    OS:           Linux 3.16.0-53-generic amd64

    groovy -version
    Groovy Version: 2.4.5 JVM: 1.8.0_66 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

Tho me a bone??

Comment: You would think it would all be "com.oracle" by now.

Comment: Make sure, your gradle running the jdk, not jre, since tools.jar is by default in classpath if you have jdk installed.

Comment: Thx. Will verify. IMHO since Gradle is a **BUILD** tool there should be some big red flashing lights for that. Jus sayin. They should fix that.

Comment: Apparently this was environmental. I got rid of all the Mint open-jdk stuff and updated to the latest jdk from Oracle instead of getting it from the java PPA. Now the problem is gone.